# Equivalent for FinePrint

Tags: software-recommendation, printing

FinePrint is a program that allows you to print multiple pages of a document's printout per physical sheet by shrinking the printouts, and merge several documents' printout into a single print job.

Is there an equivalent for OS X?

I asked this question on superuser three years ago: https://superuser.com/questions/17466/mac-equivalent-of-fineprints-ability-to-merge-print-jobs . w00t's answer of AppleScripting plus PDFLab sounded too complex. siva's answer of using the layout configuration doesn't address how to merge printouts together. My answer of using preview wasn't too bad, but it seems to be a little fiddly. You'd have to save each printout to a separate PDF, and then manually merge each document into a single document. By contrast, with FinePrint, each new printout is merged by default into a FinePrint file that you're working on.

Are there any better alternatives?

Answer (score 3):

I use the standard print dialog: under Layout you can select how many pages you want on a sheet of paper, their order, and wether they are surrounded by a frame:

http://content.screencast.com/users/vilmoskoerte/folders/Jing/media/e286324f-535f-4108-84f5-35b02090c598/00000151.png

This seems to serve at least one of the requirements you state above ("print multiple pages of a document's printout per physical sheet"). The other requirement is easy to be met if your documents are PDF files (or converted to PDF before) using Preview.